# Where do we get the list of environment variable for NiFi Docker

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I'm a beginner in NiFi setup. I'm planning to start a NiFi cluster on Kubernetes. In normal installation, I saw that, we can change the NiFi configurations under the file 'nifi.properties'. But, when it comes to docker image, I also saw that we can change that by using environment variables. In most of the cases, the properties mentioned in the nifi.properties file can be easily converted into its equivalent environment variable.

Eg:
`nifi.web.http.host <=> NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST`

But in some cases, the environment variable is different. Eg:

`nifi.zookeeper.connect.string != NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING`

From where do we get the full list of NiFi environment variable for Docker image. Any help like links or directions is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter the docker container you can see `secure.sh` and `start.sh` under the path `/opt/nifi/scripts`. These are the scripts that make all `prop_replace`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the documentation (or the source code) of the NiFi docker images your are using. For example [agturley/nifi](https://hub.docker.com/r/agturley/nifi) and [apache/nifi](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/).